# Yii2 - How to user multiple table (model) in a single form

Tags: yii2

I need to use multiple table in a single form, on form submitted the data will save in multiple tables in the data base, also wants to perform validation and update.

Comment: Please provide details. What you have already tried? Even draft of code will be better than nothing.

Comment: I wants to user two model (link with table in the database) in a single form, user will fill the form and user's input will store on both table. So how can i do it?

Comment: Still too broad. Add some code.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question(without code)
I have two table in the database and i had generated two model base on those table via 'gii'. I have a form, where user make input and submit it. 
What i wants is to store the form values to two table (database), and also able to update/delete it.
I know how to do that by single table (model) but not know how to do it with two ( or more) tables. Each table has its own model.
Hope to get some answer now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii2 saving form with multiple models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704045/yii2-saving-form-with-multiple-models)

Answer (score -1):

I suggested snippet of code, at beginning of controller class define

```
private $_rel = null;
```

controller action ,

```
public function actionSaveUser(){
 if (!empty($_POST['Contact'])){
    $model = new Contact;
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Contact'];
    if ($model->save()){
        $this->_rel = new Address;
        $this->_rel->attributes = $_POST['Contact']; 
        if ($this->_rel->save()){
            $this->render('view_name');
        } else{
            throw new CHttpException(404, 'Something went wrong message..'); 
        }
    }
 }
}
```

I hope this code help you.

Comment: The question is about Yii2, not Yii1.